# How can I export a Jar file on multiple paths on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to export a Non-Runnable JAR project in more than one path with only one export, is that possible?

I'm using Eclipse Jee 2018-12 on a Windows Server 2012 r2 machine

When I open the Export wizard, I can only select one path to export my project to, so I would have to use the Export wizard more than once to export it on more than one place.
What I thought about was jardesc, I could generate as many jardescs as I want to export my project to more than one place, but I want to know if there is a better way before doing so.
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gradle to export jar files to miltiple locations if need be. Look at [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).